# Getting symbolic values of bit vectors in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, bitvector

I want to use Z3 for reasoning over bit vectors. In addition with the satisfiability decision I also want the symbolic representations of the bit vectors so that I can apply my own computations on them as needed. For example:

Let,

> 1. X[3:0], Y[3:0], Z[4:0] are declared as bit vectors without initializing any value
> 2. print X[3:0]
> 3. X[3:0] <- X[3:0] >> 1 (logical shift)
> 4. print X[3:0]
> 5. Z[4:0] <- X[3:0] + Y[3:0]
> 6. print Z[4:0]
> 7. .......

Desired output (something symbolic like this):

```
> 2. [x3 x2 x1 x0]
> 4. [0 x3 x2 x1]
> 6. [s4 s3 s2 s1 s0]
```

Is it possible to have this using Z3?

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not possible. After simplification of the formula, Z3 employs a bit-blaster (translation to Boolean variables) and runs a SAT solver, which (usually) returns exactly one assignment to all the Boolean variables (and thus, after translation, to the bit-vector variables).

The tactic that Z3 employs for QF_BV formulas can be seen [here](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/tactic/smtlogics/qfbv_tactic.cpp). For some (simple) formulas it may be sufficient to extract the formula after bit-blasting in your case; the [Strategies Tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies) describes how to construct and apply such tactics.